# NuxtJS i18n [vue-router] Route with name about_us___en does not exist

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

Im using nuxtjs 2.10.x and i18n module. Nu custom middleware or anything like that. The routing is working fine.

my `nuxt.config.js` modules/i18n part:

```
    ...
modules: [
'@nuxtjs/axios',
'@nuxtjs/pwa',
'@nuxtjs/auth',
'@nuxtjs/dotenv',
'nuxt-fontawesome',
[
  'nuxt-i18n',
  {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-US',
        file: 'en.json',
        name: 'English'
      },
      {
        code: 'zh',
        iso: 'zh-CN',
        file: 'zh.json',
        name: '简体中文'
      }
    ],
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'locales/',
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
    differentDomains: false,
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: 'en'
    },
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: 'lang'
    }
  }
    ]
  ],
...
```

pages folder structure:

```
  'pages/'
    |--'contact_us.vue'
    |--'_lang/'
         |--'contact_us.vue'
```

But I'm getting this crazy warning: `[vue-router] Route with name 'contact_us___en' does not exist`. Actually nuxt is giving similar warning for the all pages I have. And there is no any clue why it's like that. What is possibly wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error is thrown by the `localePath()` function used to generate urls for the current locale.

Curiously it does not work by manipulating the passed in url, but by trying to match the name property of the route as defined in vue router:

[image]

Which means to find the url for a page we need to write it as follows:

```
localePath('index')       >>>   "/"
localePath('login')       >>>   "/login"
localePath('tech-test')   >>>   "/tech/test"
```

The following ways would throw an error and default to '/'

```
localePath('/')            >>>   "/"
localePath('/login')       >>>   "/"
localePath('tech/test')    >>>   "/"
```

Documentation: https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/basic-usage.html#nuxt-link

**Edit:**
I have submitted a pullrequest that would allow the use of paths as string:

```
localePath('/')          >>>   "/"
localePath('/tech/test') >>>   "/tech/test"
```

https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n/pull/554

Comment: I got your point. And I see now in the documentation examples they use `localePath('index')`. Before I've seen somewhere  `localePath('/')`

Comment: yes i wrote it right hte first time. but not in the samples.

Comment: i will try to submit a pull request, because this is not a nice way to write routes.

Comment: BTW can I do something like this `<nuxt-link :to="localePath('index') + 'products/' + someModel.slug">`?

Comment: Yes, but `localePath('index')` can result in `"/"` or `"/fr"`. Which means sometimes youll have to add a >`'/' + 'products/'` and sometimes not.

Comment: you could use , `(temp1.localePath('index') + '/products/').replace('//','/')`

Comment: Thank you. Will it affect the perfomance? currently I'm using `(this.localePath('index') == '/' ? '/': this.localePath('index') + '/') + ...`

Comment: considering how much more logic the localePath function has (200 lines),  I would suggest calling it only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <nuxt-link :to="localePath({ name: 'your-dynamic-path' })">
    Some text...
  </nuxt-link>
```

This is how I configured mine.